# Маркировка блоков исходного текста многочленами

Tags: алгоритм, криптография

Тема немного связана с [предыдущей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443209/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5/443266#443266)

В криптографии редко требуется шифровать только один символ сообщения. Обычно сообщение разбивается на блоки, например, по 5 символов. Каждому такому блоку ставится в соответствие многочлен, который затем подается на вход шифрующей функции. Результат - другой многочлен - преобразуется в десятичное число, которое потом раскладывается по основанию 256. Коэффициенты в этом разложении являются кодами символов блока зашифрованного текста.

В примере по ссылке выше поле состоит только из 256 многочленов. То есть замаркировать можно только 256 символов. И здесь возникает проблема: если требуется маркировать блоки из 5 символов, то для этого понадобится по крайней мере 256^5 многочленов, потому что всего существует 256^5 таких блоков. Поля из 256 многочленов слишком мало.

Как на практике решается эта проблема? Я вижу, что в криптографии почти всегда используется поле GF(2^8), причем используется в блочных шифрах. Каким образом маркируются длинные блоки в этих алгоритмах?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, символ занимает 2 или 4 байта, поскольку в 1 байт (256 различных символов) не помещаются все возможные буквы. Или символы кодируются в кодировке с переменным количеством байт на символ.

Насколько я понимаю, происходит следующее. Символы кодируются и образуется поток байтов. Этот поток режется на части длиной, равной длине блока шифрования. Эта длина определяется алгоритмом шифрования и ничем больше. При этом разрез может вполне приходится *между* байтами, соответствующими одному символу. Каждый из блоков шифруется, и складывается в выходной поток байтов.

Наверное, длина блока в 5 байт не слишком велика, и на практике используются бóльшие блоки. Но это не меняет алгоритм.